# formulas such that either "$\mathcal{M} \vDash \phi$, then $\mathcal{M} \vDash \psi$" or "$\mathcal{M} \vDash \phi \rightarrow \psi$"

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'd appreciate your help with the following: 
I am looking for formulas $\phi$ and $\psi$ (in any suitable language $\mathcal{L}$) such that in the following exactly one condition is fulfilled, the other not:

a) For all $\mathcal{L}$-structures $\mathcal{M}$: if $\mathcal{M} \vDash \phi$, then $\mathcal{M} \vDash \psi\\$.

b) For all $\mathcal{L}$-structures $\mathcal{M}$: $\mathcal{M} \vDash \phi \rightarrow \psi \\ \\$

($\mathcal{M} \vDash \phi$ means that the formula $\phi$ is valid in $\mathcal{M}$)

I am looking forward to your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same convention that Mauro does:

> We assume the "usual" convention that, if $\phi$ has a free variable $x$, then $\mathcal M \vDash \phi$ iff $\mathcal M \vDash (\forall x) \phi$.

a first-order example that actually works is:

- $\mathcal L$ consists of a single binary predicate $<$.
- $\phi$ is $x<y$
- $\psi$ is $y<x$.

It is clear that (a) holds: For every $\mathcal M$ such that $\mathcal M\vDash(\forall x)(\forall y)\,x<y$ we also have $\mathcal M\vDash(\forall x)(\forall y)\,y<x$.

But (b) does not hold: There is an $\mathcal M$ such that $\mathcal M \not\vDash (\forall x)(\forall y)(x<y \to y<x)$. Namely, $\mathcal M$ can be taken to be any set with a non-symmetric binary relation.

Comment: Thank you for your example, Henning! 
But I seem to not get the whole thing since I still don't see how Mauros example is false. What do you mean by the $\{<, 0, 1\}$-structure? Is there one binary relation < and two constants 0,1 in the language? Or is $\{0,1\}$ a specific universe of some specific structure that reveals the incorrectness of his example?

Comment: @Studentu: Since Mauro suggests the formulas $0<x$ and $1<x$, his language must contain constant symbols $0$ and $1$ and a binary predicate $<$, so I'm assuming that his $\mathcal L$ is $\{{<},0,1\}$. Where his example becomes not-an-example is that he tries to specify the _particular_ $\mathcal L$-structure $\mathbb N$, whereas your question was about properties that were phrased as "for _all_ $\mathcal L$-structures $\mathcal M$.

Comment: I know from Mauro's answers to other questions that his understanding of mathematical logic is excellent, so I can only assume that he must have misread the question and thought you were looking for an example of $\phi$ and $\psi$ _together with_ a particular $\mathcal M$.

Comment: @Studentu: As I said in my comment to Mauro's answer, it is an example of $\phi$ and $\psi$, such that your (a) is false and your (b) is also false. Since you asked for an example where _exactly one_ of them is true, that doesn't work. Which of that do you disagree with?

Comment: @ Henning Makholm: Thank you for your detailed reply. I thought I had misunderstood it somehow, but I get the point that Mauros example was for a specific structure. I don't disagree with you anywhere, I just have diffictulties with seeing for which structures (which universes instead of the natural numbers) his example doesn't work.

Comment: @Studentu: I described one such structure in my comment under Mauro's answer. Perhaps more explicitly: the universe of $\mathcal M$ is $\{a,b\}$; the constants are interpreted as $0^{\mathcal M}=a$, $1^{\mathcal M}=b$; and $<^{\mathcal M}$ is the relation $\{(a,a),(a,b)\}$.

Comment: @ Henning Makholm: Oh, now I see it! Thank you very much for your patience and help!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that $\vDash (\phi \to \psi)$ implies "if $\vDash \phi$, then $\vDash \psi$" but not vice versa.

A simple example with propositional logic.

We have that :

> $\nvDash [(P \to Q) \land (P \lor R)] \to (P \to R)$.

We can check with an assignment $v$ such that : $v(P)=v(Q)=\text T$ and $v(R)=\text F$.

But we have that :

> "if $\vDash (P \to Q) \land (P \lor R)$, then $\vDash(P \to R)$" holds,

because the antecedent : $\vDash (P \to Q) \land (P \lor R)$, is false.

---

A lilttle bit tricky example with FOL is the following :

> let $\phi$ be $(0 < x)$ and $\psi$ be $(1 < x)$

and consider the structure $\mathbb N$.

We assume the "usual" convention that, if $\phi$ has a free variable $x$, then $\mathcal M \vDash \phi$ iff $\mathcal M \vDash (\forall x) \phi$.

Thus, we have that :

> $\mathbb N \nvDash (0 < x) \to (1 < x)$.

But again, we have that :

"if $\mathbb N \vDash (0 < x)$, then $\mathbb N \vDash (1 < x)$" holds,

because the antecedent is false.

---

In the same way, we can easily manufacture a suitable counter-example for the case with all structures $\mathcal M$ [see Hemming's answer below].

Comment: Note that the (a) part of the question explicitly quantifies over all structures. So I don't think there can be a propositional example. It's conceivable that we can have first-order examples due to the "invisible universal closure" but I don't think yours is one if we quantify over all $\{{<},0,1\}$-structures.

Comment: @Henning Makholm: Thanks for your comment. But I don't understand what you mean. 
Am I correct that both the (a) and the (b) - part quantify over all structures? 
Anyways, I was looking for an example in FOL, not in prop. logic. The example with $(\mathbb{N}, <)$ as a structure looks just fine to me. Where do you see the problem there? 
What do you mean by quantifying over all $\{<, 0, 1\}$-structures?

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA: Thanks for your answer! It was very confusion to me that such formulas can exist, but now it makes sense to me what the main point is.

Comment: @Studentu - you are welcome :-) The propositional example has only a "pedagocical" value : to show the "subtle" point about $\vDash$.

Comment: @Studentu: Mauro's FOL example is not an example of what you want. _Both_ of your conditions (a) and (b) are false for that example. An $\mathcal M$ that witnesses the falsehood of either of them is the structure with two individuals $0$ and $1$, and whose $<$ relation makes $0<0$ and $0<1$ true but $1<0$ and $1<1$ false.

Comment: (Note that you don't get to choose what $\mathcal M$ is -- each of (a) and (b) explicitly asserts that so-and-so is true _for every $\mathcal L$-structure $\mathcal M$_).